# want to get all sizes of item with web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I wrote a code and everything is fine. My code getting one size of product accuratly but I want to get all sizes so please have a look at my code and suggest me what should I have to use.
**Note:**  **some product have one size and some have more than one so here is a link of product that has more than 1 size**
**link:** https://craftshack.com/collections/new-beers-in-stock/products/3-fonteinen-oude-geuze

here is my code:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import pandas as pd

crafts = []

for x in range(1,42):
    url = f'https://craftshack.com/collections/new-beers-in-stock?page={x}&t=1607006336486'
    s = HTMLSession()
    r = s.get(url)
    r.html.render(timeout=60)
    products = r.html.xpath('//*[@id="CollectionSection"]/div[3]',first=True)
    for item in products.absolute_links:
        r = s.get(item)
        name = r.html.find('h1.product-single__title',first=True).text
        price = r.html.find('span.product__price',first=True).text
        descrpt = r.html.find('div.product-single__description',first=True).text
        size = r.html.find('fieldset.variant-input-wrap', first=True)

        for siz in size.text:
               if siz!='':
                   sizz = siz

               else:
                   sizz = 'None'

        if r.html.find('div.btn btn--full add-to-cart disabled'):
            stock = 'Out of Stock'
        else:
            stock = 'In Stock'

        final = {
            'Name':name,
            'Price':price,
            'Stock':stock,
            'Description':descrpt,
            'Size':sizz
        }
        print(f'Getting data from page{x}')
        crafts.append(final)
    print(f'Page {x} completed successfully')
    df = pd.DataFrame(crafts)
    df.to_csv(r'F:\Crafts.csv')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. First grab the div `'fieldset.variant-input-wrap'`. It has two div of size. Then for loop iterate through get the size.

```
 mysize = r.html.find('fieldset.variant-input-wrap')
        for x in mysize:
            print( x.text )
```

here is full code. You have to rearrange code for your expected output.

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import pandas as pd

crafts = []

for x in range(1,3):
    url = f'https://craftshack.com/collections/new-beers-in-stock?page={x}&t=1607006336486'
    s = HTMLSession()
    r = s.get(url)
    r.html.render(timeout=60)
    products = r.html.xpath('//*[@id="CollectionSection"]/div[3]',first=True)
    for item in products.absolute_links:
        r = s.get(item)
        name = r.html.find('h1.product-single__title',first=True).text
        price = r.html.find('span.product__price',first=True).text
        descrpt = r.html.find('div.product-single__description',first=True).text
        size = r.html.find('fieldset.variant-input-wrap', first=True)
        mysize = r.html.find('fieldset.variant-input-wrap')
        for y in mysize:
            print( y.text )

        for siz in size.text:
               if siz!='':
                   sizz = siz

               else:
                   sizz = 'None'

        if r.html.find('div.btn btn--full add-to-cart disabled'):
            stock = 'Out of Stock'
        else:
            stock = 'In Stock'

        final = {
            'Name':name,
            'Price':price,
            'Stock':stock,
            'Description':descrpt,
            'Size':sizz
        }
        print(f'Getting data from page{x}')
        crafts.append(final)
    print(f'Page {x} completed successfully')
    df = pd.DataFrame(crafts)
    df.to_csv(r'Crafts.csv')
```

Comment: hi thanks for your help but when I run with this I got: TypeError: 'Element' object is not iterable. could you please adjust your part of code into my code ,

Answer (score 0):

If you look for `data-product-sku` in the html, you can construct a url that returns every known attribute of any given product.

For example one of the products has a `data-product-sku` of `el-segundo-steve-austins-broken-skull-ipa`

We can construct the url `https://craftshack.com/products/el-segundo-steve-austins-broken-skull-ipa.js`

Load this url and you will see that it is a json object with all product data.  You can loop over this to collect all of the data you want.

I don't use `requests_html` but I can show you a basic selenium script, which I'm sure you could use or adapt.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import requests

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://craftshack.com/collections/new-beers-in-stock?page=1&t=1607006336486")


products = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('stamped-product-reviews-badge')


product_data = []
for p in products:
    j = p.get_attribute('data-product-sku')
    product_data.append(requests.get(f'https://craftshack.com/products/{l}.js').json())
```

A look at one of the results `product_data[5]`

```
{'id': 1340072394832,
 'title': "El Segundo Steve Austin's Broken Skull IPA",
 'handle': 'el-segundo-steve-austins-broken-skull-ipa',
 'description': '<p><strong>IPA - American | </strong>6.7 % ABV</p>\n<p><strong>Commercial Description:\xa0</strong></p>\n<p><span id="_description3" itemprop="description">A bad-ass 6.7% IPA designed by Steve Austin and ESBC for the working man &amp; woman. It features Citra, Cascade, and Chinook hops to deliver big flavor with an easy finish. Now stop reading and start enjoying this awesome beer! Cheers! Steve</span></p>',
 'published_at': '2018-05-09T14:32:16-07:00',
 'created_at': '2018-05-09T14:32:17-07:00',
 'vendor': 'El Segundo Brewing Co.',
 'type': 'Beer',
 'tags': ['16oz',
  '50-100',
  'beer',
  'beers-in-stock',
  'brand-el-segundo',
  'city-el-segundo',
  'Collaboration',
  'Color-9',
  'country-US',
  'el-segundo-brewing-co',
  'feature-collaboration',
  'featured',
  'flavor-hop',
  'india-pale-ale',
  'ipa',
  'Low stock',
  'over-100',
  'Popular',
  'size-16oz',
  'size-22oz',
  'state-California',
  'style-IPA',
  'sub-style-american-ipa',
  'type-btl',
  'type-can',
  'under-10',
  'US',
  'x180111',
  'x180312',
  'x180419',
  'x180503',
  'x180523',
  'x180623',
  'x180713',
  'x180823',
  'x181006',
  'x181017',
  'x181214',
  'x190131',
  'x190304',
  'x190314',
  'x190329',
  'x190711',
  'x190725',
  'x190831',
  'x191205',
  'x191227',
  'x200302',
  'x200320',
  'x200403',
  'x200410',
  'x200417',
  'x200501',
  'x200508',
  'x200610',
  'x200617',
  'x200624',
  'x200708',
  'x200722',
  'x200729',
  'x200805',
  'x200812',
  'x200911',
  'x200916',
  'x201028',
  'x201124',
  'z170330',
  'zCraftBeerGuild'],
 'price': 599,
 'price_min': 599,
 'price_max': 17299,
 'available': True,
 'price_varies': True,
 'compare_at_price': None,
 'compare_at_price_min': 0,
 'compare_at_price_max': 0,
 'compare_at_price_varies': False,
 'variants': [{'id': 29136377380944,
   'title': '16OZ CAN',
   'option1': '16OZ CAN',
   'option2': None,
   'option3': None,
   'sku': 'El-Segundo-Steve-Austins-Broken-Skull-IPA-16OZ-CAN',
   'requires_shipping': True,
   'taxable': True,
   'featured_image': {'id': 11833571967056,
    'product_id': 1340072394832,
    'position': 1,
    'created_at': '2019-08-30T17:57:06-07:00',
    'updated_at': '2020-07-21T20:46:11-07:00',
    'alt': "El Segundo Steve Austin's Broken Skull IPA",
    'width': 480,
    'height': 480,
    'src': 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0227/0581/products/El-Segundo-Steve-Austins-Broken-Skull-IPA-16OZ-CAN.JPG?v=1595389571',
    'variant_ids': [29136377380944]},
   'available': True,
   'name': "El Segundo Steve Austin's Broken Skull IPA - 16OZ CAN",
   'public_title': '16OZ CAN',
   'options': ['16OZ CAN'],
   'price': 599,
   'weight': 227,
   'compare_at_price': None,
   'inventory_quantity': 155,
   'inventory_management': 'shopify',
   'inventory_policy': 'deny',
   'barcode': '856650004888',
   'featured_media': {'alt': "El Segundo Steve Austin's Broken Skull IPA",
    'id': 2564976803920,
    'position': 1,
    'preview_image': {'aspect_ratio': 1.0,
     'height': 480,
     'width': 480,
     'src': 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0227/0581/products/El-Segundo-Steve-Austins-Broken-Skull-IPA-16OZ-CAN.JPG?v=1569501666'}},
   'requires_selling_plan': False,
   'selling_plan_allocations': []},
  {'id': 31506914869328,
   'title': '12PK (SHIPPING INCL)',
   'option1': '12PK (SHIPPING INCL)',
   'option2': None,
   'option3': None,
   'sku': 'El-Segundo-Steve-Austins-Broken-Skull-IPA-12PK-16OZ-CAN',
   'requires_shipping': True,
   'taxable': True,
   'featured_image': {'id': 13766174343248,
    'product_id': 1340072394832,
    'position': 4,
    'created_at': '2019-12-09T16:20:12-08:00',
    'updated_at': '2020-07-21T20:46:23-07:00',
    'alt': "El Segundo Steve Austin's Broken Skull IPA",
    'width': 480,
    'height': 480,
    'src': 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0227/0581/products/broken-skull-12pk.png?v=1595389583',
    'variant_ids': [31506914869328]},
   'available': True,
   'name': "El Segundo Steve Austin's Broken Skull IPA - 12PK (SHIPPING INCL)",
   'public_title': '12PK (SHIPPING INCL)',
   'options': ['12PK (SHIPPING INCL)'],
   'price': 9599,
   'weight': 0,
   'compare_at_price': None,
   'inventory_quantity': 10,
   'inventory_management': 'shopify',
   'inventory_policy': 'deny',
   'barcode': '270249882',
   'featured_media': {'alt': "El Segundo Steve Austin's Broken Skull IPA",
    'id': 5939130892368,
    'position': 4,
    'preview_image': {'aspect_ratio': 1.0,
     'height': 480,
     'width': 480,
     'src': 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0227/0581/products/broken-skull-12pk.png?v=1587311453'}},
   'requires_selling_plan': False,
   'selling_plan_allocations': []},
  {'id': 31506921619536,
   'title': '24PK (SHIPPING INCL)',
   'option1': '24PK (SHIPPING INCL)',
   'option2': None,
   'option3': None,
   'sku': 'El-Segundo-Steve-Austins-Broken-Skull-IPA-24PK-16OZ-CAN',
   'requires_shipping': True,
   'taxable': True,
   'featured_image': {'id': 13766215499856,
    'product_id': 1340072394832,
    'position': 5,
    'created_at': '2019-12-09T16:27:47-08:00',
    'updated_at': '2020-07-21T20:46:27-07:00',
    'alt': "El Segundo Steve Austin's Broken Skull IPA",
    'width': 480,
    'height': 480,
    'src': 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0227/0581/products/broken-skull-24pk.png?v=1595389587',
    'variant_ids': [31506921619536]},
   'available': True,
   'name': "El Segundo Steve Austin's Broken Skull IPA - 24PK (SHIPPING INCL)",
   'public_title': '24PK (SHIPPING INCL)',
   'options': ['24PK (SHIPPING INCL)'],
   'price': 17299,
   'weight': 0,
   'compare_at_price': None,
   'inventory_quantity': 1,
   'inventory_management': 'shopify',
   'inventory_policy': 'deny',
   'barcode': '270248365',
   'featured_media': {'alt': "El Segundo Steve Austin's Broken Skull IPA",
    'id': 5939172048976,
    'position': 5,
    'preview_image': {'aspect_ratio': 1.0,
     'height': 480,
     'width': 480,
     'src': 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0227/0581/products/broken-skull-24pk.png?v=1587311453'}},
   'requires_selling_plan': False,
   'selling_plan_allocations': []},
  {'id': 12281610993744,
   'title': '22OZ BTL',
   'option1': '22OZ BTL',
   'option2': None,
   'option3': None,
   'sku': 'El-Segundo-Steve-Austins-Broken-Skull-IPA-22OZ-BTL',
   'requires_shipping': True,
   'taxable': True,
   'featured_image': {'id': 3657369583696,
    'product_id': 1340072394832,
    'position': 3,
    'created_at': '2018-05-09T18:19:26-07:00',
    'updated_at': '2020-07-21T20:46:18-07:00',
    'alt': "El Segundo Steve Austin's Broken Skull IPA",
    'width': 480,
    'height': 480,
    'src': 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0227/0581/products/El-Segundo-Steve-Austins-Broken-Skull-IPA-22OZ-BTL_4cc4a3cc-dd7f-4990-8f06-d1455e52fc96.png?v=1595389578',
    'variant_ids': [12281610993744]},
   'available': False,
   'name': "El Segundo Steve Austin's Broken Skull IPA - 22OZ BTL",
   'public_title': '22OZ BTL',
   'options': ['22OZ BTL'],
   'price': 1099,
   'weight': 454,
   'compare_at_price': None,
   'inventory_quantity': 0,
   'inventory_management': 'shopify',
   'inventory_policy': 'deny',
   'barcode': '856650004154',
   'featured_media': {'alt': "El Segundo Steve Austin's Broken Skull IPA",
    'id': 1559808475216,
    'position': 3,
    'preview_image': {'aspect_ratio': 1.0,
     'height': 480,
     'width': 480,
     'src': 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0227/0581/products/El-Segundo-Steve-Austins-Broken-Skull-IPA-22OZ-BTL_4cc4a3cc-dd7f-4990-8f06-d1455e52fc96.png?v=1569310832'}},
   'requires_selling_plan': False,
   'selling_plan_allocations': []}],
 'images': ['//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0227/0581/products/El-Segundo-Steve-Austins-Broken-Skull-IPA-16OZ-CAN.JPG?v=1595389571',
  '//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0227/0581/products/El-Segundo-Steve-Austins-Broken-Skull-IPA-4PK-16OZ-CAN.JPG?v=1595389575',
  '//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0227/0581/products/El-Segundo-Steve-Austins-Broken-Skull-IPA-22OZ-BTL_4cc4a3cc-dd7f-4990-8f06-d1455e52fc96.png?v=1595389578',
  '//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0227/0581/products/broken-skull-12pk.png?v=1595389583',
  '//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0227/0581/products/broken-skull-24pk.png?v=1595389587'],
 'featured_image': '//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0227/0581/products/El-Segundo-Steve-Austins-Broken-Skull-IPA-16OZ-CAN.JPG?v=1595389571',
 'options': [{'name': 'Size',
   'position': 1,
   'values': ['16OZ CAN',
    '12PK (SHIPPING INCL)',
    '24PK (SHIPPING INCL)',
    '22OZ BTL']}],
 'url': '/products/el-segundo-steve-austins-broken-skull-ipa',
 'media': [{'alt': "El Segundo Steve Austin's Broken Skull IPA",
   'id': 2564976803920,
   'position': 1,
   'preview_image': {'aspect_ratio': 1.0,
    'height': 480,
    'width': 480,
    'src': 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0227/0581/products/El-Segundo-Steve-Austins-Broken-Skull-IPA-16OZ-CAN.JPG?v=1569501666'},
   'aspect_ratio': 1.0,
   'height': 480,
   'media_type': 'image',
   'src': 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0227/0581/products/El-Segundo-Steve-Austins-Broken-Skull-IPA-16OZ-CAN.JPG?v=1569501666',
   'width': 480},
  {'alt': "El Segundo Steve Austin's Broken Skull IPA",
   'id': 2564976836688,
   'position': 2,
   'preview_image': {'aspect_ratio': 1.0,
    'height': 480,
    'width': 480,
    'src': 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0227/0581/products/El-Segundo-Steve-Austins-Broken-Skull-IPA-4PK-16OZ-CAN.JPG?v=1569501666'},
   'aspect_ratio': 1.0,
   'height': 480,
   'media_type': 'image',
   'src': 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0227/0581/products/El-Segundo-Steve-Austins-Broken-Skull-IPA-4PK-16OZ-CAN.JPG?v=1569501666',
   'width': 480},
  {'alt': "El Segundo Steve Austin's Broken Skull IPA",
   'id': 1559808475216,
   'position': 3,
   'preview_image': {'aspect_ratio': 1.0,
    'height': 480,
    'width': 480,
    'src': 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0227/0581/products/El-Segundo-Steve-Austins-Broken-Skull-IPA-22OZ-BTL_4cc4a3cc-dd7f-4990-8f06-d1455e52fc96.png?v=1569310832'},
   'aspect_ratio': 1.0,
   'height': 480,
   'media_type': 'image',
   'src': 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0227/0581/products/El-Segundo-Steve-Austins-Broken-Skull-IPA-22OZ-BTL_4cc4a3cc-dd7f-4990-8f06-d1455e52fc96.png?v=1569310832',
   'width': 480},
  {'alt': "El Segundo Steve Austin's Broken Skull IPA",
   'id': 5939130892368,
   'position': 4,
   'preview_image': {'aspect_ratio': 1.0,
    'height': 480,
    'width': 480,
    'src': 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0227/0581/products/broken-skull-12pk.png?v=1587311453'},
   'aspect_ratio': 1.0,
   'height': 480,
   'media_type': 'image',
   'src': 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0227/0581/products/broken-skull-12pk.png?v=1587311453',
   'width': 480},
  {'alt': "El Segundo Steve Austin's Broken Skull IPA",
   'id': 5939172048976,
   'position': 5,
   'preview_image': {'aspect_ratio': 1.0,
    'height': 480,
    'width': 480,
    'src': 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0227/0581/products/broken-skull-24pk.png?v=1587311453'},
   'aspect_ratio': 1.0,
   'height': 480,
   'media_type': 'image',
   'src': 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0227/0581/products/broken-skull-24pk.png?v=1587311453',
   'width': 480}],
 'requires_selling_plan': False,
 'selling_plan_groups': []}
```